# How to make a copy of all modified files in Mercurial working copy

Tags: windows, powershell, mercurial

How can I make a copy of all uncommited modified or added files in a Mercurial working copy?

Obviously I can go to each directory that has a changed file and copy it.  I am looking for a process I can do from the command line (Windows or Powershell) or using TortoiseHg.

Thanks
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use purge alias from [hgrc man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) as good starting point and

- Change status command accordingly to your needs: `hg status --no-status -m`
- Pipe output to xargs's cmd.exe [oneliner equivalent](http://davidpthomas.wordpress.com/2007/01/04/xargs-in-dos/) `hg status ... > filelist.txt && FOR /F %k in (filelist.txt) DO copy %k \BACKUPPATH\%k` (status without -0 parameter) or install any xargs port (as part of [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki), for example) and use original form of alias `status -0 ...|xargs -0 ...`